# Heroku: Am I paying when I do “heroku run console”?

Tags: heroku

I have run three commands individually (`bash`, `console` and `node`).

When I do `heroku ps` I get this:

```
 $ heroku ps
Process       State               Command
------------  ------------------  ------------------------------
run.1         complete for 11m    console
run.2         complete for 8m     bash
run.3         complete for 3s     node
```

Am I paying for those 3 processes? I can’t kill them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The state of those processes is `complete`.  They continue to be shown by `heroku ps` for a little bit of time but should they only count against your dyno hours when they are actually running.  Here is an except from the [dyno pricing article](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-much-does-a-dyno-cost) on the Heroku dev center:

> Dynos cost $0.05 per hour, prorated to the second. For example, an app
>   with four dynos is charged $0.20 per hour for each hour that the four
>   dynos are running.