# Unable to “run:stop” on Heroku

Tags: clojure, heroku

When I run `heroku run lein repl`, I don't seem to be able to shut down the process. I can do the following, and be exited from heroku's repl

```
    $ heroku  stop run.1
    Stopping run.1 process... done
    $ heroku  stop run.2
    Stopping run.2 process... done
    $ heroku  stop run.3
    Stopping run.3 process... done
    $ heroku stop run.4
    Stopping run.4 process... done
```

I hope to god I am not [being billed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064619/heroku-am-i-paying-when-i-do-heroku-run-console). Both `heroku stop` and `heroku ps:stop` ([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743039/killing-abandoned-process-on-heroku)) fail to remove the runs from a `heroku ps` listing.

```
    $ heroku ps  
    Process  State             Command 
    -------  ----------------  ------------------------  
    run.1    complete for 26m  lein repl                     
    run.2    complete for 16m  lein repl                     
    run.3    complete for 7m   lein repl                     
    run.4    complete for 2s   lein repl
```

How do I do that? Or do I just need to wait for the complete listing to disappear?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those items are not running, but are complete.  A running instance will be showing as `up for xm` where xm is the time in minutes.  `complete` shows you how long that process has been stopped for.

For more info on heroku ps, [see here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ps).

To be extra sure you're not being billed, you could ask support.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to confirm. Thanks.